# Upload local docker image to AWS ECR using golang sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, go, amazon-ecr

```
mySession := session.Must(session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
    Region:      aws.String(<region>),
    Credentials: credentials.NewStaticCredentials(<access_key>, <secret>, ""),
}))
ecrClient := ecr.New(mySession)

ecrClient.PutImage(&ecr.PutImageInput{
    ImageManifest:  <????????????>
    RepositoryName: aws.String(<ecr_address>),
})
```

In the above code, I have created an ECR client using my `access key` and `secret`.

I want to push a locally build docker image (say `example:v1`) to AWS ECR.

How to create the ImageManifest for this purpose ?

Comment: This is one of the few AWS services you do not typically access via the SDK. Typically you access via the `docker` command. Otherwise, `PutImage` should only be called after uploading the image layers.

Comment: You'll have to call GetAuthorizationToken for a short term docker auth token, then use the standard docker sdk to push.